# How to switch between windows

Tags: unity

I'm looking to quickly switch between to windows of an application in Unity. I looked at [Unable to switch between different windows of the same application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147891/unable-to-switch-between-different-windows-of-the-same-application) but I didn't get any answer.

The only option I've got is to long-click on the icon on the dash and click on the window when they're all shown. That's definitely too long ! I'm sure there is a shortcut, like an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but I don't find it.

So, how can I quickly switch between windows of an application ?

Comment: whats the console command to start switch between open windows in linux?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In "System Settings.." --> "Keyboard" go to 'Shortcuts' tab. At the left choose "Navigation". Scroll down to "Switch windows of an app directly", and assign the keyboard shortcut you'd like (I'm using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>).
Hope that works for you.

Comment: I tried a lot of combinations but each time the shortcut isn't reconized. Do you need a reboot or something ?

Comment: I also found this "feature" of unity incredibly annoying.  I tried following the advice of Gil, but to no avail.  Here's what finally worked for me: set the shortcut for "switch applications" to something like Alt+tab, then set the shortcut for "switch windows of an application" to something else like Alt+q.  (Note that these settings have the *opposite* effect of what you might expect -- i.e., Alt+tab toggles the windows of a single application, while Alt+q toggles multiple applications.)

Comment: Setting "Switch windows of an app directly" to `Alt`+` worked for me without a reboot.

Comment: @WilliamDeMeco, notice there are 2 separate options listed:"switch windows of an application"  and "Switch windows of an app directly". The second one does the trick.

Answer (score 15):

At least in 13.04, you should be able to do this with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>§</kbd> (the key above <kbd>tab</kbd>, at least on Swiss keyboards).

Comment: On a de keyboard layout it is: ALT + ^

Comment: life changing :)

Answer (score 4):

I discovered two ways of doing so.

1. Use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> until the desired app gets marked. Then wait a little while until the seperate windows of the application show up.
2. When you have one window of the application active, click on the applications icon on the quick launch bar. You should now see all of the applications windows.
3. To switch to the previously selected application hold <kbd>alt</kbd> und press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

Another suggestion is switching between workspaces.
Just put a window of your application on several workspaces. You can switch between these workspaces really fast using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow-key(up, down, left, right)</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you, but that's already what I'm doing. I need a faster method, like one click or one shortcut, because I do that all the time and I can't spend 2s switching windows.

Comment: Ok how about switching between 2 workspaces then? I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Yes, that could do it, but when I open a lot of windows and don't want to assign them to a different workspace just so I can switch between them. I know, I'm very picky :)

Comment: Ok last suggestion before I run out of steam :-) What about shwitching to the previous application? I've added this to my answer. Though I find it hard to utilize it may work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on what @CedricReichenbach posted, <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> works excellently for me on an English keyboard.

Comment: thanks for this. Have been looking for this for a while. Note: this is useful if you have many of the same application open. For example if you have 5 terminals open, alt+tab just switches between the last 2 terminals used. However, 'alt  ~' can switch between each of the terminals one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer for those who still find this search result:

Alt+Tab is default for switch between apps ignoring windows. You can wait a bit and thumbnails of actual windows will come up, nice for completely new users but not very useful as speed is the whole point of keyboard shortcuts.

But actually a quick Alt+Tab and release will always switch between the top-most 2 previous selected windows, even if they are of the same app. This is a more or less insane behaviour when you spell it out like this, but in practice it is nice for old habits.

Alt+~(above Tab) is default for switch between windows of same app only. A little awkward unless you are a Mac power user or something. But what is very nice about this is that you can hold Alt and use Tab or key above at will. Which is to say you can Tab to drill down to the app you know you want and then key above to the specific window without ever releasing Alt until you are done.

More good options have come on board over time (both in 13.04 I think). They are not keyboard shortcuts but are really good for exploring everything that is open if you have gotten very busy or cluttered:

1. you can right-click any launcher tile and see windows only of that app are in that list.
2. you can scroll the mouse wheel over any launcher tile to immediately switch between windows only of that app.

Keyboard shortcuts are not really ideal for this because they are instead for when you know exactly what you want to switch to.

See: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/new-window-switching-method-added-to-unity

Answer (score 1):

Following @CedricReichenbach notice, it is already possible on french keyboard with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>²</kbd> (which is indeed the key above <kbd>tab</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to show all active windows, and then use <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between them.

see this: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-switching.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a seamless switch between the **same application** but a **different window** along with the **other applications** then this extension does the exact same thing:

[WindowSwitcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6060/windowswitcher) ✅